# i using the load function in jquery for ajax work

Tags: jquery, function, caching

i using the load function in jquery for ajax work.
when the first time loaded(second page),the javascript loaded.
when the scrolling the second page also loade with javascript file for again.

when using javascript, the action for 2 or n time Performance.

i want the javascript file loaded for first time and not loaded when second time.

thanks
ime sorry for bad typing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can load a specific part of a page with JQUERY such as using an ID selector.
So, if your javascript is in the `<head>` tag in your loaded page you can just load everything else by using this and that way you will avoid reloading any javascript.

```
$(".content").load( page_url + ' #main_content');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: thanks for answer, but when next part loaded("url #id"),in this part dont work JS code. :(